# CakePHP multiple request

Tags: php, cakephp

I am facing the issue of multiple request at same time.I am checking in DB if this data exists then not insert the same record.

Using cakephp 2.6 version

```
 $userdata = $this->MobappFan->find('first', array(
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'MobappFan.id' => 123,
                                        'MobappFan.mobapp_id' => 234,
                                        'MobappFan.deleted' => 0
                                    ),
                                    'fields' => array('MobappFan.id', 'MobappFan.status', 'MobappFan.blocked'),
                                    'contain' => false
                                )
                            ); 
if(!$userdata) {
  $this->MobappFan->save($this->request->data);
}
```

But due to same request with same parameters is not able to find the existing record.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "due to same request... is not able to find the existing record"?  This is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

I think basically you just want to not check in the current posted id

you can do this as below

```
 $userdata = $this->MobappFan->find('first', array(
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'MobappFan.id' => 123,
                                    'MobappFan.id !=' => $this->request->data['MobappFan']['id'],
                                    'MobappFan.mobapp_id' => 234,
                                    'MobappFan.deleted' => 0
                                ),
                                'fields' => array('MobappFan.id', 'MobappFan.status', 'MobappFan.blocked'),
                                'contain' => false
                            )
                        ); 
if(!$userdata) {
      $this->MobappFan->save($this->request->data);
}
```

or

```
$userdata = $this->MobappFan->find('first', array(
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'MobappFan.id' => 123,
                                    "NOT" => array( 'MobappFan.id' => $this->request->data['MobappFan']['id']),
                                    'MobappFan.mobapp_id' => 234,
                                    'MobappFan.deleted' => 0
                                ),
                                'fields' => array('MobappFan.id', 'MobappFan.status', 'MobappFan.blocked'),
                                'contain' => false
                            )
                        ); 
if(!$userdata) {
  $this->MobappFan->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Hope this helps. If you can explain more what you need then I can write a better conditions or you can check details [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a condition to check for a specific ID, then follow it up with a condition to make sure it's NOT a specific ID.  One OR the other, but not both.

Comment: yes I agree, actually the details provided are not clear and that is the reason I asked rahul about the specific requirement.